# How could I generate signal output as a slow clock domain that is a multiple of a fast clock domain?

Tags: vhdl, clock, digital

I have an FPGA which I have 40-60 MHz clock domain I am working with. My output will be a slow multiple of that clock domain.

So if I have 40 MHz oscillator, the output interface would be 5 MHz.

I was planning on using a clock divide by 2 and sending the signal to the input, but I don't like this design because I read about how I would need to send the signals through a clock buffer which I may not have enough resources and others have stated it could create hold violations. (https://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/pulse-stretching.377607/)

My second idea is to use a counter that counts the amount of time required to hold the Q output of a DFF and apply back pressure to source logic.

I currently do not have code. I am still thinking of it conceptually.

The initial plan was use several clock divide by 2 block in series to get the output desired.

For signals that seem like a 5 MHz clock domain but were generated with a 40 MHz clocked system, what is the terminology for this type of clock domain crossing?

Are there any other options?

Thank You

Comment: It's not clear what the output interface is. At least provide the entity/module signals you're using.

Comment: The output would be Clock Data Enable. But I would like to transform any 4x clock domain signal to an x clock domain signal. So a 40 ns pulse high should be a 160 ns pulse.

Comment: 40 Mhz divided down to 5 MHz requires a divisor of 8, not 4. But this doesn't really matter for your question.

Comment: Do you need the slow clock outside of the FPGA or inside for the rest of your logic? FPGAs used to have multiple clock buffers giving multiple clock domains. You should be able to feed a second clock buffer with the output of the divider. Which FPGA do you plan to use?

Comment: If the 5Mhz clock is used only externally, then you are often ok just driving it directly from an output pin from logic.

Comment: If you're only outputting signals then indeed as mentioned above you can use a counter to divide the clock and all logic will remain at the 40MHz domain.

Comment: the slow clock domain is meant solely for external FPGA usage. Sorry for using random values (divide by 8 vs 4). I'm making up the numbers right now and just thinking of the concept right now.

Comment: But for the sink which these signals will be used at (the 5 MHz domain), is there a terminology for this type of signal generation or clock domain division? Meaning, a clock domain that is actually a fast clock that is divide by a couple factors.

Comment: Is there a good reason why you don't simply use exactly the same clock but update your data only every 8 (or 4 or whatever) clock cycles?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I think that is what I am trying to do with the counter instead of a clock divider. I just don't know the terminology that defines this method.

Answer (score 0):

This is a synchronous CDC, and the counter approach belongs to a class of FSM based clock dividers.